# Springboot repository could not be found

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, dependency-injection, spring-repositories

I have issue with this error. - Springboot cannost inject JPARepository.

```
    Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-02-19 10:07:59.712 ERROR 6912 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field enginePartRepository in cz.fry.bmw.OM.services.OrderService required a bean of type 'cz.fry.bmw.OM.DAO.coreid.EnginePartRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'cz.fry.bmw.OM.DAO.coreid.EnginePartRepository' in your configuration.
```

**On my computer working everything OK but If I want deploy app on Windows server as windows service with WinSW.NET4.exe application crash with this error.**

I have two data source (two different SQL databases on same server) first database working OK.

I already tryed `@EntityScan` `@ComponentScan` withou success.
I tryed remove repository but every repository from this database throw this error.

```
@ComponentScan
@EntityScan("cz.fry.bmw.om.DAO")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
public class OrderManagementApplication {
```

[[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQqaH.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQqaH.png)

I am running Java 11, Springboot 2.4.2. and MSSQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need `@EnableJpaRepositories`

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"cz.fry.bmw.om.DAO"}) <---------
@ComponentScan
@EntityScan("cz.fry.bmw.om.DAO")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
public class OrderManagementApplication {
```

2 more things that I have noticed.

**1)**

```
"cz.fry.bmw.om.DAO"
```

in your project structure it seems like

```
"cz.fry.bmw.OM.DAO"
```

**2)**

```
@ComponentScan
```

provide the root package here

```
@ComponentScan("cz.fry.bmw.OM");
```

Comment: If I added It stop working also on my machine :-|

Comment: with what error? You definetly need the annotation that I have written here

Comment: Thank you ! Bad configuration and om -> OM was issue.
Thank you very much!